# React-Redux mapStateToProps value is undefined after being set by reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to initialize the state of my app with some dummy data for testing, but I can't get it to render. According to the console logs I have in place below, it seems that the data exists in the application state, but when I try to access it in my TweetList component, it is undefined despite using connect and mapStateToProps. Any idea why that is?

This is the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
   7 | class TweetList extends Component {
   8 |   renderTweetBlocks(tweetArray) {
>  9 |     return this.props.tweetListTweets.map((tweet) => {
  10 |       return <TweetBlock key={tweet.tweet_id} tweet={tweet} />;
  11 |     });
  12 |   }
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import reducers from './reducers';
import App from './App';

let store = createStore(reducers);
console.log(store.getState());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**reducer_tweetlist.js**

```
/* eslint-disable */
import { DROP_IN_CATEGORY } from '../actions/index';

export default function( state = {
    tweetListTweets: [
    {username: "user1", content: "content1", tweet_id: "1"},
    {username: "user2", content: "content2", tweet_id: "2"},
    {username: "user3", content: "content3", tweet_id: "3"},
    {username: "user4", content: "content4", tweet_id: "4"},
    {username: "user5", content: "content5", tweet_id: "5"}]
  }, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case DROP_IN_CATEGORY:
      const id = action.payload.tweet.tweet_id;
      return state.tweetListTweets.filter(tweet => tweet.tweet_id != id);
  }
  return state;
}
```

**TweetList.js**

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TweetBlock from './TweetBlock';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchNewTweet } from '../actions/index';

class TweetList extends Component {
  renderTweetBlocks(tweetArray) {
    return this.props.tweetListTweets.map((tweet) => {
      return <TweetBlock key={tweet.tweet_id} tweet={tweet} />;
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="tweet-list">
        {this.renderTweetBlocks()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchNewTweet }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { tweetListTweets: state.tweetListTweets };
}

TweetList = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TweetList);
export default TweetList;
```

This is the result of the console.log(store.getState()) in index.js, so it seems *tweetListTweets* should exist in the state.

```html
{TweetListReducer: {…}}
TweetListReducer:
  tweetListTweets:
    Array(5)
    0: {username: "user1", content: "content1", tweet_id: "1"}
    1: {username: "user2", content: "content2", tweet_id: "2"}
    2: {username: "user3", content: "content3", tweet_id: "3"}
    3: {username: "user4", content: "content4", tweet_id: "4"}
    4: {username: "user5", content: "content5", tweet_id: "5"}
    length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

This is the result of the console.log(this.props) in TweetList.js, which shows tweetListTweets being undefined despite using mapStateToProps.

```
{tweetListTweets: undefined, fetchNewTweet: ƒ}
  fetchNewTweet: ƒ ()
  tweetListTweets: undefined
```

Comment: can you show me the file where you have combined the reducers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to access it within your `TweetListReducer`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { tweetListTweets: state.TweetListReducer.tweetListTweets };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When You are returning in mapStateToProps, check the value of state.tweetListTweets. It seems that it is undefined, but state is defined. Usually when you want to get something out of state of store, you do it with state.<`reducer_name`>. tweetListTweets. I don't know exactly how you have defined it in the reducers.js. But this should provide gist towards the solution.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { tweetListTweets: state.<reducer_name that you have defined in reducers.js>.tweetListTweets };
}
```

Easy way, just console.log the state in mapStateToProps and find where 
tweetListTweets is.